# Redo log member and control files at Oracle DB Standard Edition

Tags: oracle, transaction-log, license, standard-edition

I am planing to dive into the oracle database world. Since the oracle database is such a complex machine, I want to inform myself as good as possible, before I start. I have some questions.

How many redo log members for each group can I define and how many control files can I use by using the standard edition (one)?

I've read, that I can have only two archive log destinations defined by `LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST` and `LOG_ARCHIVE_DUPLEX_DEST` in the standard edition (one). Now I am wondering, if there is any limitation by multiplexing redo log members and control files by using the standard edition (one) ?

I couldn't find this information except, that there can be 8 control files at all.

Answer (score 2):

> How many redo log members for each group can I define?

[Database Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/appg_db_lmts.htm#UNXAR015)

MAXLOGMEMBERS

- Default: 2
- Maximum Value : 5

> How many control files can I use by using the standard edition (one)?
>   I couldn't find this information except, that there can be 8 control
>   files at all.

That is correct. [CONTROL_FILES](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-1D609657-4283-40DA-8A57-8097E719281C.htm#REFRN10021)

- Range of values:1 to 8 filenames

> I've read, that I can have only two archive log destinations defined
>   by LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST and LOG_ARCHIVE_DUPLEX_DEST in the standard
>   edition (one).

`LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST` and `LOG_ARCHIVE_DUPLEX_DEST` are deprecated long ago. [LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_N](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/log_arch_dest_param.htm#SBYDB01100) is available since 8.1 in EE, and 10.1 in SE. You can define up to 31 destinations, but only the first 10 can be local. Remote destinations are not supported in SE.

Comment: I am confused about you saying log LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST and LOG_ARCHIVE_DUPLEX_DEST are deprecated at all. Here [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams113.htm#REFRN10085) you can read, that those two parameters are deprecated for enterprise edition users only. I also have read, that standard edition (one) user have to use those two.

Comment: About the amount of redo log member per group and the amount of control files: Do I understand it in the right way, that standard edition (one) users can use the maximum values you have mentioned (redo: max 5 per group; cf: 8 files) without any limitation? Or is there any limitation in number compared to the enterprise edition?